# Is there a way to exclude axis values in the Charts framework for SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I am trying to figure out how to display sports gambling data into SwiftUI Charts and there doesn't seem to be a way to exclude axis values. In gambling -/+ 100 is the 0 point and the values between should be exclude as they are not possible. Is there a way to use .chartYScale(range: ), to solve this issue?

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct GameLine: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let time: Date
    let line: Int
}

struct Event {
    let league: String
    let team1: String
    let team2: String
    let gameLines: [GameLine]
}

struct Gamble: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let event: Event
    let title: String
}

final class LineChartTestingViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func createSampleData() -> [Gamble] {
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let gameLine1: GameLine = GameLine(id: "gameline1", time: calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -7, to: Date())!, line: 100)
        let gameLine2: GameLine = GameLine(id: "gameline2", time: calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -6, to: Date())!, line: 110)
        let gameLine3: GameLine = GameLine(id: "gameline3", time: calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -5, to: Date())!, line: 150)
        let gameLine4: GameLine = GameLine(id: "gameline4", time: calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -4, to: Date())!, line: -120)
        let gameLine5: GameLine = GameLine(id: "gameline5", time: calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -3, to: Date())!, line: -130)
        let gameLine6: GameLine = GameLine(id: "gamline6", time: calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -2, to: Date())!, line: 100)
        let gameLine7: GameLine = GameLine(id: "gameline7", time: calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: Date())!, line: 160)
        let gameLines = [gameLine1, gameLine2, gameLine3, gameLine4, gameLine5, gameLine6, gameLine7]
        
        let event1: Event = Event(league: "NFL", team1: "Bears", team2: "Packers", gameLines: gameLines)
        let event2: Event = Event(league: "NFL", team1: "Bears", team2: "Vikings", gameLines: gameLines)
        let event3: Event = Event(league: "NFL", team1: "Bears", team2: "Lions", gameLines: gameLines)
        let event4: Event = Event(league: "NFL", team1: "Bears", team2: "Redskins", gameLines: gameLines)
        let event5: Event = Event(league: "NFL", team1: "Bears", team2: "Chiefs", gameLines: gameLines)
        
        let gamble1: Gamble = Gamble(id: "gamble1", event: event1, title: "Bears vs Packers")
        let gamble2: Gamble = Gamble(id: "gamble2", event: event2, title: "Bears vs Vikings")
        let gamble3: Gamble = Gamble(id: "gamble3", event: event3, title: "Bears vs Lions")
        let gamble4: Gamble = Gamble(id: "gamble4", event: event4, title: "Bears vs Redskins")
        let gamble5: Gamble = Gamble(id: "gamble5", event: event5, title: "Bears vs Chiefs")
        
        let gambles: [Gamble] = [gamble1, gamble2, gamble3, gamble4, gamble5]
        
        return gambles
    }
}

struct LineChartTesting: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = LineChartTestingViewModel()
    @State private var gambles: [Gamble]?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(gambles ?? []) { gamble in
                Chart(gamble.event.gameLines, id: \.id) {
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Time", $0.time),
                        y: .value("Line", $0.line)
                    )
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            gambles = viewModel.createSampleData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify how you want the chart to look? Do you just want to omit certain labels on the y-axis? What about the associated grid lines? Or do you want to draw a different line as well? An image of how it should look would be very helpful.

Comment: So in your sample data, gameLine1 and gameLine6 should always be excluded from the charts because their values are not possible?

Comment: [Y-Axis example] (https://sportshandle.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Positive-and-Negative-Moneyline-Odds.png). Does this help clarify?